# controlar back navegador

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, chrome, navegador-web

Tengo una duda, en javascript ( o php), como puedo controlar el botón BACK del navegador. Lo que me gustaría hacer es que me muestre un listado y al hacer back en el histórico del navegador me salte 2 páginas atrás.

Tengo claro que es window.history.go(-2), pero solo quiero que lo haga cuando hagan click en ATRAS dentro del navegador, debe haber una opción / función que lo controle, pero la desconozco.

Sería algo así como

Si botón atras presionado
Ir a window.history.go(-2)

gracias

Comment: Ir hacia atrás en el historial de navegación no es recomendado en ningún caso y el usuario se debería abstener de usarlo. Podrías capturar el evento de descarga del documento, pero no podrías diferenciar si es para cerrar la pestaña o para ir adelante, atrás en el historial o refrescar la página. Lo mejor es gestionar bien la interfaz de usuario para que el usuario no se vea tentado u obligado a usar los botones de navegación del navegador para llegar a una pantalla que debería estar accesible de una manera sencilla.

Comment: Por seguridad, no se permite modificar el comportamiento de elementos propios del navegador. Aunque podrías tratar de manipular el [historial con javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador#A%C3%B1adiendo_y_modificando_entradas_del_historial)

Comment: gracias a todos. Pero los usuarios son muy pillos y se las saben todas. Cuando hay facturación de por medio, los usuarios se buscan mil y una para poder hacer la pua...